# How to test if two cells are equal in excel using closedxml?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I need to test if two cells are equal using closedxml and this is the very basic code that I am using:

```
if ((PipeSheet.Cell(j, 3).Value == SheetToEdit.Cell(i, RegionCodeInMain).Value))
```

However, it is not working.  I put in a break point with a watch for each side, even when they were equal it was still evaluating to false.

`PipeSheet` and `SheetToEdit` along with `i` and `j` are variables I set.

What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` property returns an object, which means your program checks for reference equality, not value equality. Depending on the data type for the values use something like this:

```
if ((PipeSheet.Cell(j, 3).GetValue<int>() == SheetToEdit.Cell(i, RegionCodeInMain).GetValue<int>()))
```

or

```
if ((PipeSheet.Cell(j, 3).GetValue<string>() == SheetToEdit.Cell(i, RegionCodeInMain).GetValue<string>()))
```